# запрос mysql на php

Tags: php, mysql

помогите составить запрос которым можно определить на каком месте определенная новость, т.е., есть к примеру 20 новостей (не по порядку), как определить на каком месте находится новость 17?

Comment: На 17 месте она у вас находится :)

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "на каком месте определенная новость" ? Вы хотите узнать порядковый номер записи в таблице базы данных или рейтинг этой новости на сайте? Плюс не плохо было бы увидить структуру таблицы где хранятся новости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Выполнение SQL query */
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");
```

после чего полуаем результат запроса в массиве содержащем числовой индекс полей

```
$line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

в функции `mysql_fetch_array()` вторым параметром указиваем констану `MYSQL_NUM`  при которой столбцы возвращаются в массиве, содержащем числовой индекс полей. Этот индекс начинается с 0, первого поля результата

находим в массиве `$line` вашу новость 17, берем ключ, это и будет  ее порядковий номер в БД.

P.S. Не забываем что отсчёт начинаетя с нуля.

Comment: а как эту же процедуру сделать в случае с PDO?

Comment: @privetsh надо вызывать функцию PDOStatement::fetch() в цикле (потому что она возвращает по одному результату из набора выборки), и вторым параметром передавать флаг FETCH_NUM                                             описание функции здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: большое спасибо